# How to get past v-cloak when scraping with cheerio, axios, node js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, web-scraping, axios, cheerio

so I just started web-scrapping in node using cheerio and axios and I was trying to scrape html inner text from a website that's built with Vue.js. After console logging at a particular div where I want some data, it returned

```
   <div class="j-goods-detail-v2" v-cloak="">
     <router-view></router-view>
   </div>
```

and my code looks like this

```
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const pretty = require("pretty");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const init = async () => {
  const fetcher = await axios(
    "https://nl.shein.com/EMERY-ROSE-Sheer-Embroidery-Mesh-Bell-Sleeve-Curved-Hem-Tee-p-10461869-cat-1738.html?src_identifier=ai%3D53810%60an%3Demery-rose%60on%3DBanner%60cn%3DBanner22%60hz%3DBanner22A02%60ps%3D3%60jc%3DitemPicking_00851909&src_module=campaign&src_tab_page_id=page_activity_factory1658092077463&attr_ids=&scici=campaign_emery-rose_53810~~ON_1,CN_Banner22,HZ_Banner22A02,HI_hotZone_e6za4zfl0~~2~~itemPicking_00851909~~"
  );

  const htmlData = await fetcher.data;
  const $ = cheerio.load(htmlData);

  const detail = $('[class="j-goods-detail-v2"]');
  console.log(pretty(detail.html()));
};

init();
```

Comment: For Vuejs you probably need Puppeteer.

Comment: Thank you so much,  it worked with puppeteer plus it is a lot easier